# svn : an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: linux, apache, svn

can any help me solving this problem?

I'm getting this problem  when i am trying to access apache subversion in linux

"an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ",i'm not able to google the solution can any help me out from this problem

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question with the command you're using? Also, if using svn on the command line can you try running it with the "-v" flag (if appropriate) and post the output?

Comment: potential suplicates with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167203/svn-error-cant-write-to-connection-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with SVN and it was related to the file limit that Linux can use, try to run:

```
ulimit -a
```

The solution for me was to increase the 'open files' per process using the -n switch.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks this worked for me when pulling down a really big project